# Use LaTeX on Microsoft Word

Tags: math-software

I realized that in various mathematics textbooks, they all used the LaTeX style in mathematical equations. What software is used? I know if copy-paste from the LaTeX Equation Editor site is less efficient.  Can I use a LaTeX template or something like that in Microsoft Word?

Comment: They use LaTeX, and probably write the script in one of the common LaTeX editors.

Comment: Yeah  i know that. But, how i write equation on Microsoft word with LaTeX style?

Comment: @user516076: You don't use Word. Normally, you install the LaTeX software on your OS (TeX Live (Linux) or MiKTeX (Windows) or MacTeX (Mac OS)), then you install Tex Studio (my preferred LaTeX editor, but you can use others) and start typing. MS Word's integration with LaTeX is severely lacking, and very few articles in math or physics are typed up in Word (Perelman's proof of the Poincare Conjecture is one notable exception).

Answer (score 1):

In the new Microsoft Word (my version 2016 supports this already) go to `Insert|Equation`. In the new equation box, type LaTeX directly, and as you press `[SpaceBar]` it is instantly converted to the correct symbol.

This is a very limited use, but somewhat functional.